# Django: Messages App

Tags: python, django

Here's my model,

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    msg_content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I wants to order the Users based upon who sent a message to `request.user` or to whom `request.user` sent a message most recently! As we see on social networks.

This is what I tried,

```
users = User.objects.filter(Q(sender__receiver=request.user) | Q(receiver__sender=request.user)).annotate(Max('receiver')).order_by('-receiver__max')
```

This code is working fine only when `request.user` sends someone a message. It's not changing the ordering of messages in case if someone sends a message to `request.user`.

I also tried,

```
users = Message.objects.filter(sender=request.user, receiver=request.user).order_by("created_at")
```

But, I could't filter out the distinct users. It's showing equal number of users as messages.

How can I fix this problem? Thank You!

Comment: Isn't the 2nd query basically looking for messages that are sent to the authenticated user from the same authenticated user ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem while trying to find the conversations of the authenticated user. I used the following solution:

```
def is_message_in_list(self, conversations, message):
    for msg in conversations:
        if (msg.sender == message.sender and msg.receiver == message.receiver) or \
           (msg.sender == message.receiver and msg.receiver == message.sender):
            return True

    return False

def get(self, request):
    user = request.user
    messages = Message.objects.filter(
        Q(sender=user) | Q(receiver=user)
    ).order_by('-created_at').select_related('sender', 'receiver')

    conversations = []
    for message in messages:
        if not self.is_message_in_list(conversations, message):
            conversations.append(message)
```